# Merge data frame with other and calculate groupby percentage based on the specific condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have two data frames as shown below

df1:

```
Sports     Expected_%
Cricket    70
Football   20
Tennis     10
```

df2:

```
Region    Sports     Count    Percentage     
North     Cricket    800      75                              
North     Football   50       5            
North     Tennis     150      20           
South     Cricket    1300     65           
South     Football   550      27.5         
South     Tennis     150      7.5
```

Expected Output:

```
Region    Sports     Count    Percentage   Expected_%     Expected_count    
North     Cricket    800      75           70             700
North     Football   50       5            20             200
North     Tennis     150      20           10             100
South     Cricket    1300     65           70             1400
South     Football   550      27.5         20             400
South     Tennis     150      7.5          10             200
```

Explanation:

```
Expected_% for Cricket = 70

Total Count for North = 1000

Expected_Count for North = 1000*70/100 = 700
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join for new column, then use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `sum` for new `Series`, multiple by new column and divide by `100`:

```
df = df2.merge(df1, on='Sports', how='left')
summed = df.groupby('Region')['Count'].transform('sum')
df['Expected_count'] = summed.mul(df['Expected_%']).div(100)
print (df)
  Region    Sports  Count  Percentage  Expected_%  Expected_count
0  North   Cricket    800        75.0          70           700.0
1  North  Football     50         5.0          20           200.0
2  North    Tennis    150        20.0          10           100.0
3  South   Cricket   1300        65.0          70          1400.0
4  South  Football    550        27.5          20           400.0
5  South    Tennis    150         7.5          10           200.0
```

Or use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for new column:

```
df2['Expected_%']= df2['Sports'].map(df1.set_index('Sports')['Expected_%'])
summed = df2.groupby('Region')['Count'].transform('sum')
df2['Expected_count'] = summed.mul(df2['Expected_%']).div(100)
print (df2)
  Region    Sports  Count  Percentage  Expected_%  Expected_count
0  North   Cricket    800        75.0          70           700.0
1  North  Football     50         5.0          20           200.0
2  North    Tennis    150        20.0          10           100.0
3  South   Cricket   1300        65.0          70          1400.0
4  South  Football    550        27.5          20           400.0
5  South    Tennis    150         7.5          10           200.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
map_dict = dict(df1.values)
df2['Percentage'] = df2.groupby('Region').apply(lambda x: (x['Count'].sum() * x['Sports'].map(map_dict))).div(100).values
```

Comment: Performance... Rather avoid this, because slow.

Comment: @jezrael Ohh!!.. I've not checked this for the performance!!

Comment: Ya, depends of data, I guess 10times slowier, but maybe more.

Comment: @jezrael 10 times is huge!! :P Will try to evaluate performance sometime later!!. Thanks for the advice though ;)

Comment: Simply general rule - native pandas functions are fast, custom function not. If call a bit complicated function per groups, then performance decrease because `groupby.apply`, because complicated function, and because call N times (number of group)s

Comment: @jezrael makes sense!!